# POSTFIX - SMTP Authentication fails

Tags: postfix

I'm pretty new to POSTFIX.
When I connect to my LXD containers, some have "new mail in /var/mail/root". As those inboxes are not consulted, I would like to reroute them to another inbox on an Exchange Server (O365 one).

I successfully configured other apps with the following parameters:

```
['smtp_enable'] = true
['smtp_address'] = "mail.external-smtp-exchange.com"
['smtp_port'] = 587
['smtp_user_name'] = "noreply@subdomain.contoso.com"
['smtp_password'] = "<pwd>"
['smtp_domain'] = "subdomain.contoso.com"
['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
['smtp_tls'] = false
```

I would like all users using one single 'noreply' address (FROM) when routing mails. Hence modified `/etc/aliases` that way:

```
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: noreply@subdomain.contoso.com
```

Followed by `newaliases` to reload everything.

Content of  `main.cf` file

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no
# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = core-keycloak.internal-domain.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, subdomain.contoso.com, core-keycloak, localhost.localdomain, localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

relayhost = [mail.external-smtp-exchange.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtp.sasl
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = no
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
### Tried also parameters below without any improvement
smtp_generic_maps =  regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_generic_maps
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps =  regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

Without the last 4 parameters overriding the FROM email I get the following output:

```
Jun  8 13:23:21 core-keycloak postfix/smtp[18264]: 86C822CE8A: to=<bob@contoso.com>, relay=mail.external-smtp-exchange.com[<SMTP-IP>]:587, delay=2995, delays=2989/0.01/5.3/0, dsn=4.7.3, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; server mail.external-smtp-exchange.com[<SMTP-IP>] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful)
Jun  8 13:23:23 core-keycloak postfix/pickup[18261]: 413752CEAA: uid=0 from=<noreply@subdomain.contoso.com>
Jun  8 13:23:23 core-keycloak postfix/cleanup[18271]: 413752CEAA: message-id=<20220608112323.413752CEAA@core-keycloak.winternal-domain.com>
Jun  8 13:23:23 core-keycloak postfix/qmgr[18262]: 413752CEAA: from=<noreply@subdomain.contoso.com>, size=408, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

With last 4 parameters overriding the FROM email I get the following output:

```
Jun  8 13:25:23 core-keycloak postfix/pickup[18334]: 68B772CEB0: uid=0 from=<noreply@subdomain.contoso.com>
Jun  8 13:25:23 core-keycloak postfix/cleanup[18346]: 68B772CEB0: message-id=<20220608112523.68B772CEB0@core-keycloak.internal-domain.com>
Jun  8 13:25:23 core-keycloak postfix/qmgr[18335]: 68B772CEB0: from=<noreply@subdomain.contoso.com>, size=408, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

In both situation I ain't getting any message in my Exchange Inbox.

Any help would be more than welcome.

---

**EDIT**

I have special characters in password like `!([])` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your relay does not specify the reason, "SASL authentication failed" could man different things.

1. It could mean that you are not meant to send your credentials via unencrypted connections. You may have been mislead by the naming of the options, in Postfix `smtp_use_tls` is a *deprecated* shorthand to *enable* opportunistic transport security, where in other software this name refers to *disabling* the (in this context obsolete) STARTTLS mechanism, instead setting up transport security right away.

   **Remove`smtp_use_tls` from your `main.cf`, and instead use `smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt`.**
   The latter configuration applies a policy independently from the mechanism in use, affecting *all* outgoing SMTP, both TLS on port 465 (called tls_wrappermode by Postfix) *and* STARTTLS on port 587.
2. It could mean your password or username is incorrect, or read from a stale cache. Besides colons in the username, and besides leading/trailing whitespace, I do not know of any character special treatment.

   **Verify that the credentials  read by postfix match what you tested with other software:**

   ```
   # postmap -v $(postconf -xh smtp_sasl_password_maps)
   postmap: open hash /etc/postfix/smtp.sasl

   # postmap -q "$(postconf -xh relayhost)" $(postconf -xh smtp_sasl_password_maps)
   noreply@subdomain.contoso.com:<pwd>
   ```

Keep in mind you address mapping configuration might not have had any effect on your previous tests, as Postfix by default ships with configuration preventing excessive retries to hosts already known to not accept credentials and/or mail, hence the lack of a `postfix/smtp` log line for later attempts. Inspect your queue (`postqueue -p`) for potential outstanding messages.

Comment: Still not working, however you should be right regarding my settings that are illogical. However it’s coming from our internal IT and have no hand on it.

Comment: Managed to configure successfully the SMTP I had on my internal server so will accept your answer as is for the sake ! Many thanks